# How can I display the custom fields number with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to display a number on recent post widget.First I add a custom field and call "kekoa" and set value,than I put the code on recent post widget functions.

```
// Check if post has post thumbnail.
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                            $html .= '<div class="mainumber33">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "yeniyazinumarasi", true) . '</div>';
$yeniyazinumarasi= $html;
echo $yeniyazinumarasi;
                                $html .= '<a class="rpwe-img" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '"  rel="bookmark">';
                                    if ( $image ) :
                                        $html .= '<img class="' . esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb" src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
                                    else :
                                        $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(),
                                            array( $args['thumb_width'], $args['thumb_height'] ),
                                            array(
                                                'class' => $args['thumb_align'] . ' rpwe-thumb the-post-thumbnail',
                                                'alt'   => esc_attr( get_the_title() )
                                            )
                                        );
                                    endif;
                                $html .= '</a>';
```

I can see the css box,but I can't see the number what I set.

UPDATE.FİXED

```
// Check if post has post thumbnail.
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                            $html .= '<div class="mainumber33">' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "kekoa", true) . '</div>';
                                $html .= '<a class="rpwe-img" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '"  rel="bookmark">';
                                    if ( $image ) :
                                        $html .= '<img class="' . esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb" src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
                                    else :
                                        $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(),
                                            array( $args['thumb_width'], $args['thumb_height'] ),
                                            array(
                                                'class' => $args['thumb_align'] . ' rpwe-thumb the-post-thumbnail',
                                                'alt'   => esc_attr( get_the_title() )
                                            )
                                        );
                                    endif;
                                $html .= '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
        $html = '<div class="mainumber33">';
        $html .= get_post_meta($post->ID, "kekoa", true);
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<a class="rpwe-img" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">';
        if ( $image ) :
            $html .= '<img class="' . esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb" src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
        else :
            $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(),
                array( $args['thumb_width'], $args['thumb_height'] ),
                array(
                    'class' => $args['thumb_align'] . ' rpwe-thumb the-post-thumbnail',
                    'alt'   => esc_attr( get_the_title() )
                )
            );
        endif;
        $html .= '</a>';
```

You have a bunch of typos

Comment: sorry, revised my code above, have a try with new line,

Comment: not working again.I update my frist message.Maybe I do something wrong.Can you check it

Comment: updated my answer, try this.
Do you have a online version of it?

Comment: Not work again.This time display just one post and css fields disappear.I bakc to the orjinal code.You can see on  http://www.onbilim.com/ The numbers should display in orange circle on sidebar .

Comment: can you please post your complete code? your edited code doesn't make sense

Comment: I can't put on here.Also I try $post->ID to get_the_ID() but widget cloned it self.Full code. https://codeshare.io/G6DADN

Comment: fixed.Updated first message